# Doxygen unable to open directory with dot files for state graphs

Tags: doxygen, dot

I'm using Doxygen and dot on Win7 to document my code.  I'm trying to include some state diagrams using `\dotfile` in the comment block at the beginning of some C files.

In the files I have something like

```
/***************************************************************************//**
 *    ...
 *  \dot
 *  \dotfile state_diagram_1.gv
 *  \enddot 
 *    ...
 ******************************************************************************/
```

Looking at the doxy.log file shows that Doxygen is unable to open the directory where the .gv files are.  I have `HAVE_DOT = YES` in the doxy.cfg file (and know it works because placing actual dot code between the `\dot` and `\enddot` flags works).  I have the directory where `state_diagram_1.gv` is located specified with `DOTFILE_DIRS = dot_files` in doxy.cfg.  The directory dot_files is located at the same level as doxy.cfg.  I have tried messing around with what `DOTFILE_DIRS` is set to (including an absolute path) to no avail.

I have further tried removing the \dot and \enddot flags and I still get this warning regardless: `warning: source dot_files is not a readable file or directory... skipping.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a python script to generate the Doxygen files.  I was assuming that the the directory specified with `DOTFILE_DIRS` was relative to the doxy.cfg file (because some other things in doxy.cfg are like `HTML_OUTPUT`).  My issue was solved by specifying `DOTFILE_DIRS` relative to where my python script was located.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this fixes the problem, but you should use \dotfile instead of \dot...\enddot, and not put it inside the block.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but you're right.  It didn't fix my problem.  I added some info to my original post to say I've tried it with and without the flags, with an absolute path, and with a relative path.  It feels like I'm just missing some small setting in the doxy.cfg file, but I haven't found it yet :(